# How does Facebook, Google + Share Buttons Work?

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, share, google-plus

Does anybody have an idea of how the facebook/google+ share buttons work, the ones that are located on websites, blogs, etc? I know its javascript, iframe etc, but could sure use an in depth analysis and maybe a starting point from one of the guru's on here. It would surely be appreciated. I have an amazing unique idea for a new api that would sit next to those other social share buttons and really want to get it out the door here.

I am not going to place any code, because I am looking for foundation so it can be done right, not fixing what I have now. I'm also not looking for anyone to take 5 hours out of their day, just looking for a starting point, maybe a point in the right direction.

Thanks, I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the presentation from Google I/O where we talk about how the +1 button was built: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rlbTVkyJc4

Comment: Thank you so much. Seriously Appreciated.